# Why is a custom SyntaxNode subclass not working with parentheses?

Tags: ruby, treetop

I have a treetop grammar like below:

```
grammar Addme

  rule AddExpr
    Num '+' Num
  end

  rule Num
    [0-9]+ <ExprNumber>
  end

end
```

This is working when I parse the expression:

```
g = AddmeParser.new
t = g.parse("1234+56789")
```

. . . there is a syntax node that matches `"1234"` with type `ExprNumber`.
But, if I add parentheses to the rule like this:

```
rule Num
    ([0-9]+) <ExprNumber>
end
```

It will not match the class `ExprNumber`. Why would this happen?

Comment: The [documentation](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/semantic_interpretation.html) explains this a little bit. It may be because when it is in parentheses it is treating it like there should be a matching module instead of a class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't really get the idea of parentheses in this case? How it prevent type subclass

Comment: The node has already been created inside the parentheses. A module can be mixed in, but not a class.

Comment: I check the treetop grammar, after parentheses the node-subclass definition is not allowed there so it does not generate the subclass. I am closing this now.

Comment: This is still listed as an open question. I copied my comment to the answer below. Please accept this so it stops appearing as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The node has already been created inside the parentheses. A module can be mixed in, but not a class.